# Wordpress QR Code Widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, qr-code

Basically, I've been trying to make a simple Wordpress widget that displays a QR code with the URL of the current page. I'm using a modififed version of the simple text widget that parses PHP too.

```
function the_qrcode($permalink = '', $title = '') {
    if($permalink && $title == '') {
        $permalink = 'http://eternityofgamers.com/forums';
        $title = 'Forums';
    }

    echo '<img src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' .$permalink. '" alt="QR: ' .$title. '"/>;
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this? I get a 500 error when I add it to `functions.php`.

Comment: "pretty sure"? Have you tested it? What is wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work, so I am sure I failed miserably. No errors show up. Sorry for not being clear. >_<

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before any other line and tell me whats the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
<?php
    function the_permalink( $permalink ) {
        if ($permalink == '') {
            echo '<img src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=http://eternityofgamers.com/forums" alt="QR Code">';
        } else {
            echo '<img src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data='.$permalink;
        }
    }
?>
```

(*I've corrected a bunch of syntax errors*)

Comment: Using this code, and adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, still turns back no errors.

Comment: @KeithGadberry, It shouldn't to. It means it's ok. We have just declared a function here. There's not output to be shown.

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do, as I've discovered, is make a call to an existing function; `the_permalink()` that's already in Wordpress. :/

Comment: @KeithGadberry, wait what? if there's a function called `the_permaling()` and you are trying to implement your function called as well `the_permalink()` it will clearly go in contrast. What are you really trying to achieve and what is your entire code?

Comment: As I said, I'm new to this and have almost no idea what I'm doing.
Previously I had been using `<img src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="QR: <?php the_title(); ?>"/>` as the code in the widget, and it would work. What I'm trying to do is make it to where when `the_permalink()` returns null, it changes it to `http://eternityofgamers.com/forums`. Because at the moment, the forums are the only page on my website that it doesn't work.

Comment: you could do `<img src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=<?php echo ($a = the_permalink()) ? $a : 'http://eternityofgamers.com/forums'; ?>" alt="QR: <?php echo the_title(); ?>"/>`

Comment: @Jeffery Well crap. The URL it returns for any page other than forums is basically `the_permalink()http://eternityofgamers.com/forums` :[

Comment: @Jeffery It worked, technically, but not properly. It adds `http://eternityofgamers.com/forums` to the end of every QR code that isn't the forums.

Comment: @KeithGadberry, I'm sorry but i don't know what's the entire project. What I can assure you is that when `the_permalink()` return null or false it will ad the provided url.

Comment: @Jeffery On the main page, the Qr code is this: `http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=http://eternityofgamers.com/archives/74http://eternityofgamers.com/forums` On the forums the QR code is this: `http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=http://eternityofgamers.com/forums`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function. Generally as a rule of thumb all querystring values should be url encoded.

```
function the_qrcode( $permalink = '' ) {
    if($permalink == '') {
        $permalink = 'http://eternityofgamers.com/forums';
    }

    echo '<img src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data='.urlencode($permalink);
}
```

Now you can create your QR code with:

```
the_qrcode(the_permalink());
```

Also, you had a **very bad missing equals sign**. It is very important to understand the difference between `=` and `==`. If you don't, no matter the context `=` and `==` mean two different things. `=` assigns the right hand side to the left. `==` returns true or false whether the left and right hand side are loosely equal (loosely because casting will be used if the sides are not of the same type).

Look at this example ([Codepad demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xb9ivH)):

```
$a = 5;
$b = 10;

if($a = 6) {
    echo "This always appears because when you assign a truthy (all non-zero numbers are true) to a variable, true is returned.\n";
    echo "Also a should now equal six instead of five: " . $a . "\n";
}

if($b == 10) {
    echo "This will work as expected because == is a comparison not an assignment.\n";
    echo "And b should still be 10: " . $b;
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.
PHP is so confusing.

I don't know if it's the widget or the code.

Comment: Well I'm assuming this is done within the context of a class. If you aren't writing this function for a class then you shouldn't have `public function`. You just need `function`.

Comment: Alright... So as it turns out, I've failed so miserably that I didn't realize that I'm trying to make a _call_ to a function that's built into wordpress. `<img src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="QR:  <?php the_title(); ?>"/>` There's an example of how I was using it before, and it worked. What I want to do now is just make it to where the permalink is changed to `http://eternityofgamers.com/forums` when the call to `the_permalink` returns nothing. I'm really sorry for being so stupid. >_<

Comment: What do you mean when the call to `the_permalink` returns nothing? Also, as it currently stands you should be calling `the_permalink()` like this. However, I believe `the_parmalink()` is already a Wordpress function. Perhaps you should call this some something else like `the_qrcode()` and pass the permalink into it (See updated code).

Comment: `the_permalink` is indeed already a Wordpress function, and it's a function that I am trying to call to get the URL for use in the QR code API. And right now, the only time that it returns nothing is on the forums page because of some apparent glitch in bbpress. What I'm trying to avoid though is making a new function.

Comment: @KeithGadberry Take a look at the modified code. Use `the_qrcode(the_permalink());` to create the image tag with the proper url.

Comment: Do I put the code anywhere specific? Because when I add it in with the widget, I get the same results as before, and if I add it to my functions.php file, It returns a 500 error on every page.

Comment: You should add the function's definition in the `functions.php` file but you should call it (with `the_qrcode(the_permalink());`) where you want the image (so in your template after the post or wherever you want it).

Comment: Am I doing something that ins't adding the functions definition, to the `functions.php` file? Because every time I add that code to `functions.php` I get a 500 Internal Server Error...

Comment: @KeithGadberry That's because I had one typo in the code. Try throwing it into the `functions.php` file again. You shouldn't get the 500. Then try putting the function call in the post template.

Comment: Cool, it worked! (Kinda)
I also noticed that it would be best not to use `urlencode()`, because that seems to really mess up the link.
Also, I modified it to http://pastebin.com/4UGSa2d7, and it seems to return both `the_permalink()` and `http://eternityofgamers.com/forums`. I'm so confused.

Comment: @KeithGadberry If `urlencode()` messes up the link than the API server doesn't handle HTTP requests properly. Querystring params should be url encoded. What URL do you want a QR to?

Comment: This is really cluttered, and it's down to 1 thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515478/wordpress-widget-issues I moved it to there. :s