# Wordpress Widget Issues

Tags: php, wordpress, qr-code

I'm trying to use PHP to display a QR code for the current page. `the_permalink()` returns as blank on my Forums.

```
function the_qrcode( $permalink ) {
    if($permalink == '') {
        $permalink = 'http://eternityofgamers.com/forums';
    }

    echo $permalink;
}
```

In the PHP-enabled text widget, I have `<?php the_qrcode(the_permalink()); ?>`

On the main page, `$permalink` is echoed as `http://eternityofgamers.com/archives/74http://eternityofgamers.com/forums` instead of `http://eternityofgamers.com/archives/74`.

Comment: You're misisng the QR Code bit. You need to put the QR api back in the echo

Comment: I left that out on purpose. For testing reasons. 3:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the_permalink() should be used in a Loop. If you want to get the the current post link, use the [get_permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).

```
<?php the_qrcode(get_permalink()); ?>
```